# How do I retrieve specific values from a firebase database and assign it to specific variables in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, firebase

I have a database in firebase which looks as follows:
[image]

I need to get the values of nameID, tutorID, and imageURL and assign them to variables in Swift 4. Here is what I have so far in XCode:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("students").child("student1")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            return
        }
        print (dictionary)
        let Obj = studentInformation(nameID: " ", tutorID: " ", imageURL: " ")
        Obj.imageURL = dictionary["photoID"] as? String
        Obj.nameID = dictionary["nameID"] as? String
        Obj.tutorID = dictionary["tutorID"] as? String
        self.studentInfo.append(Obj)
    }, withCancel: nil)
```

For the studentInformation class, I have declared it as such:

```
class studentInformation {
var nameID: String?
var tutorID: String?
var imageURL: String?

init(nameID: String?, tutorID: String?, imageURL: String?) {
    self.nameID = nameID
    self.tutorID = tutorID
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work correctly, as it's able to get the values from the database, but it is not able to assign it to the local variables I have in XCode. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create an optional initializer for in the Object and determine which variables should be optional (ex: only the `imageURL` is optional in the example below, and the `nameID` and `tutorID` have to be Strings otherwise the init will return nil):

```swift
init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

        guard let nameId = dictionary["nameID"] as? String,
            let tutorID = dictionary["tutorID"] as? String else { return nil }

        let imageURL = dictionary["imageURL"] as? String

        self.init(nameID: nameID, tutorID: tutorID, imageURL: imageURL)

    }
```

Then, in the Firebase listener you can create the object like this:

```swift
// Returns Optional(obj)
let obj = studentInformation(dictionary: dictionary)
```

or

```swift
// Add object to array
if let obj = studentInformation(dictionary: dictionary) { self.studentInfo.append(obj) }
```